# How get Class[_ <: A]] with lower bound

Tags: scala, reflection

Hello ) I have one abstract class and several concrete classes in Java

```
abstract class SpecificRecordBase {}
class A extends SpecificRecordBase 
class B extends SpecificRecordBase
....
```

Also I have a map in Scala. I want to put key String and value as a class to use it in method:

```
def test(m: Map[String, Class[_ <: SpecificRecordBase]]):Unit = ???
```

I tried to ClassTag(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader.loadClass(stringClassName)).runtimeClass but got an error. Also I tried to create method and use it

```
  def getClass[T <: SpecificRecordBase](ct: ClassTag[T]): Class[T] = ct.runtimeClass

And also have an error
 Error:(10, 73) type mismatch;
 found   : Class[_$1] where type _$1
 required: Class[T]
  def getClass[T <: SpecificRecordBase](ct: ClassTag[T]): Class[T] = ct.runtimeClass
```

Could you help me please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the signature of `runtimeClass`:

> ```
> def runtimeClass: Class[_]
> ```
>
> A class representing the type U to which T would be erased. **Note that there is no subtyping relationship between T and U.**

The reason is types like `Any`, `Nothing`, etc. But really, `ClassTag` isn't useful here because you are doing `ClassTag(<something>).runtimeClass` which can be simplified to `<something>`.

So just cast it:

```
ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader.loadClass(stringClassName).asInstanceOf[Class[_ <: SpecificRecordBase]]
```

(EDIT: as pointed out be Mario Galic, this should be

```
ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader.loadClass(stringClassName).asSubclass(classOf[SpecificRecordBase])
```

Similar changes applied below.)

or even simpler

```
Class.forName(stringClassName).asSubclass(classOf[SpecificRecordBase])
```

If you aren't sure whether you'll get a subtype of `SpecificRecordBase`, you can test it:

```
val cls = Class.forName(stringClassName)
Try { cls.asSubclass(classOf[SpecificRecordBase]) } match {
  case Success(cls1) =>
    // handle a subclass
  case Failure(_) =>
    // handle a non-subclass
}
```

or without exception handling

```
val cls = Class.forName(stringClassName)
if (classOf[SpecificRecordBase].isAssignableFrom(cls)) {
  val cls1 = cls.asInstanceOf[Class[_ <: SpecificRecordBase]]
  // handle a subclass
} else {
  // handle a non-subclass
}
```

Comment: Does [`asSubclass`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59914294/5205022) achieve the same purpose?

Comment: You are right, of course, I just didn't remember it (and don't think I ever saw it used).

Answer (score 2):

Try [`asSubclass`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59914294/5205022) like so

```
def getSubclass[T <: SpecificRecordBase](implicit ct: ClassTag[T]): Class[_ <: SpecificRecordBase] =
  ct.runtimeClass.asSubclass(classOf[SpecificRecordBase])

getSubclass[A]
getSubclass[B]
// res0: Class[_ <: SpecificRecordBase] = class A
// res1: Class[_ <: SpecificRecordBase] = class B
```

Out-of-the-box `asSubclass` [Java implementation](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/3d9dddd6586c6ec59b091cd7cce701a154cca587/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Class.java#L3767) is similar to Alexey's Scala one

```
public <U> Class<? extends U> asSubclass(Class<U> clazz) {
    if (clazz.isAssignableFrom(this))
        return (Class<? extends U>) this;
    else
        throw new ClassCastException(this.toString());
}
```